# Calculate some estimations of the given lemma to determine the constant

Tags: analytic-number-theory

There exists Lemma giving that, denot $\rho(n)$ as some multiplicative function, and I want to consider only for the main term $$\sum_{\substack{M<m<M_1 \\ \text{some other conditions}}}\rho(m) \approx \dfrac{\pi}{4}(M_1-M)A(q)$$

It is said (from the excerpt that I tried to catch up) that by using the lemma with partial summation $$\sum_{\substack{M<m<2M \\ \text{some other conditions}}}\dfrac{\rho(m)}{m^2}\approx \dfrac{\pi}{8}M^{-1}A(n_1n_2)$$
but as I take a calculation $$\sum_{\substack{M<m<2M \\ \text{some other conditions}}}\dfrac{\rho(m)}{m^2}=\sum_{\substack{M<m<2M \\ \text{some other conditions}}}\rho(m)\cdot\dfrac{1}{m^2}\approx \left(\sum_{\substack{M<m<2M \\ \text{some other conditions}}}\rho(m)\right)\dfrac{1}{4M^2}\approx\dfrac{\pi}{16}M^{-1}A(n_1n_2)$$
so I don't know why the constant is $1/8$ instead of $1/16$.

Comment: In the first equation, should the $2M$ in the subscript be $M_1$? In any case, your last calculation is not partial summation, but in fact a lower bound made by replacing $1/m^2$ in the sum by $1/(2M)^2$; this is not going to give a correct asymptotic formula in general. Do you know what the partial summation technique is?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have taken a look at the technique but isn't it like this? $A_m=a_M+a_{M+1}+\dots a_{m}$
$$\sum_{M<m<2M}a_mb_m=A_{2M-1}b_{2M}-\sum_{M<m<2M}A_m(b_{m+1}-b_m)$$ and I didn't account the error term of the last sum.

Comment: That's right, and you have the main term for $A_m$ from the start of the post.

Comment: But when I compute by replacing $b_{2M}=1/4M^2$, it's not exactly the same as stated in the second approximation.

Comment: The resulting summation in your comment is not an error term; it contributes to the main term. I really suggest working through it and seeing what happens.